# Update database from an event handler

Tags: php, cakephp

Using CakePHP 2.4, I'd like to update a database record from within an event handler. I understand how to fire off the event and register the event handler.

How do I do this?

Comment: Where are you firing the event from? A model? A controller? Other?

Comment: I wrote a blog post on CakePHP’s events system a couple of weeks ago, as I was similarly frustrated with it: http://martinbean.co.uk/blog/2013/11/22/getting-to-grips-with-cakephps-events-system/. Have a read and see if that’s any help.

Comment: @MartinBean It looks like I use `$this->User = ClassRegistry::init('User');`, replacing `User` with the model I'm using. That works perfectly, thanks. Feel free to make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fire an event with CakePHP, you pass a subject. You could use a model, and then have a listener listen for the event and use that model to update a database record.

I wrote a blog post a little while back on how to set up CakePHP event listeners, as I was similarly frustrated on the spare documentation surrounding it: http://martinbean.co.uk/blog/2013/11/22/getting-to-grips-with-cakephps-events-system/